# Is it wise to use edge loops and subdivision modifiers on high poly meshes?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects, vertices

in Blender tutorials i see that apart from CTRL + E, loop cuts are often used to preserve edges, despite subdivision surface modifier.

Now that I have some experience with Blender and have created meshes with more than 100,000 faces, I wonder if this is the most useful method.

Of course it is faster to add a layer of the subdivision modifier and then add loopcuts, but the bottom line is that Blender has to work with more vertices and faces.

I am aware that if the mesh is not near the camera, you can set the subdivision modifier to adaptive (cycles) or use a decimate modifier.

Now to the real question: Is it better for performance to use a subdivision modifier lv 1 and add the details yourself to reduce vertices in the end result, or to work with loop-cuts and subdivision modifier lv 2 to reduce vertices in the viewport?

Comment: Hello :). This question keeps popping up as unanswered. Please mark one of the answers as accepted **✓**, or post your own solution. Just to keep the site nice and tidy. Thanks :).

Comment: @JachymMichal I think questions with no answers or answers with no votes determine the popping... up-voted and see what happens...

Comment: @susu Good point. I used to be irritated by unsolved questions, but I don't really care anymore :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lower polycount is better performance-wise.**
But sometimes it makes sense to sacrifice performance for ease of use.

---

*Bevel modifier*
- easily adjustable edge width, great for hard surface modeling
- not suitable for complex corners and edges (creates overlaps)
- low-poly results

*Subdivision Modifier*
- easy to use, great for organic surfaces
- works almost anywhere
- hi-poly results  (4x more polygons with each level)

In reality they're often used together.

**Let's compare**
Same edge resolution, different face count.

[image]